# Determine character by regular expressions

Tags: java, character, digit

I know that for sure that a text has not digit, We can do simple this work:

```
text.matches(".*\\d.*"));     // if return true, then text has digit
```

Now, how determine a character in user input?

I need to determine character in user typed input by regular expression (because it is simpler that other functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a character set like: `[a-zA-Z]+` to match one or more letters of `A-Z` ignoring case.

You could use `\w` to match all "word characters" which includes `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Or, if you want to match any character that isn't a space, you could use `\S`.

It depends on how you define a "character" in user input...

Comment: Nice, When you say `\w` your mean is `text.matches(".*\\w.*")); ` Or `text.matches("\w"));`?

Comment: As a Java string it will be `\\w` since you have to escape it.